# Linux Command Line - list all directories containing .js files, and copy the directories and their contents to a new folder

Tags: linux, bash, file, find, copy

Here is the code I already have that finds and lists all directories containing .js files (excluding the node_modules directory).

```
find . -name '*.js*' -printf "%h\n" | sort -u | grep -v node_modules
```

As you can see, listing those directories is no problem.  However, rather than list the directories, I would like to copy them (and their contents) to a new folder, preferably all in one line without running any kind of script.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to copy the directories whole-sale, including any non-.js files they may contain?

Comment: Either way works for me.  I could just recursively delete any non-.js files if I have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to process the list of directories using NULL as the delimiter so that directories with spaces (and other odd characters) are handled correctly.

Remove the `echo` if the output looks correct.

#### "1-liner"

```
 find "/path/to/tld" -path "*node_modules*" -prune -o -name "*.js" -printf "%h\0" | \
    sort -uz | xargs -0 -I _ echo cp -a _ "/path/to/new/dir"
```

#### Bash Script

This requires Bash 4 for the associative array which will filter out duplicates.

```
#!/bin/bash

tld="/path/to/top/level/dir"
newdir="/path/to/new/dir"

unset dirHash;
declare -A dirHash

while read -r -d $'\0' dir; do
  (( ! dirHash["$dir"]++ )) && echo cp -a "$dir" "$newdir"
done < <(find "$tld" -path "*node_modules*" -prune -o -name "*.js" -printf "%h\0")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Actually both of these worked, but the one liner didn't work until I changed it to: `find "/path/to/tld" -path "*node_modules*" -prune -o -name "*.js" -printf "%h\0" | sort -uz | xargs -0 -I _ echo cp -a _ "/path/to/new/dir"`  It looks like you accidentally added a backslash in there before `sort`.  You should probably update your answer.

Comment: @ScottGreenfield the `\ ` was there for line-continuation but it looks like I added an extra space between the backslash and newline which threw off the interpreter.  I deleted the space and it should now work as-is (assuming you alter the /path/to/tld and /path/to/new/dir parts)